# Protractor - run multiple tests in parallel on different System

Tags: protractor

Is there any way to run multiple test suites in parallel on different machines.

I am able to do parallel execution in same machine with different browser.

Tried using seleniumAdress: ''/wd/hub
But its not working.

Answer (score 3):

Finally Got the answer :-)

Step 1: Start selenium standalone using following command
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -port 5041

here 5041 is a port number.

Step 2: add following line of code in your configuration file

multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: 'safari',
            shardTestFiles: true,
            seleniumAddress: 'http://IP1:5041/wd/hub',
            specs: '../xyz.js',
            maxInstances: 1
        },
        {
            browserName: 'safari',
            shardTestFiles: true,
            seleniumAddress: 'http://IP2:5041/wd/hub',
            specs: '../pqr.js',
            maxInstances: 1
        }
    ],

Note: You need start selenium-standalone in both the system.

Answer (score -3):

There may be a better way to do this but currently I am just executing these as concurrent Grunt tasks.

1) Add the grunt concurrent plugin

```
npm install grunt-concurrent --save-dev
```

2) Add a task for each browser under grunt.initConfig. We can add the browser as an arg to re-use our configuration file.

```
protractor: {
        options: {
            keepAlive: true,
            singleRun: false,
            configFile: "test/protractor.conf.js"
        },
        run_chrome: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: "chrome"
                }
            }
        },
        run_firefox: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: "firefox"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

3)  Register these as tasks;

```
grunt.registerTask('protractor-chrome', ['protractor:run_chrome']);
grunt.registerTask('protractor-firefox', ['protractor:run_firefox']);
```

4)  Create your concurrent task under grunt.initConfig

```
concurrent: {
        protractor_test: ['protractor-chrome', 'protractor-firefox']
    },
```

5) Add the grunt task for concurrent

```
grunt.registerTask('protractor-e2e', ['concurrent:protractor_test']);
```

And executing that should give you concurrent protractor tests.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I guess this will execute script in same system and 2 browsers say Chrome and firefox. Right??

Comment: Yeah! That's right. Is this the answer you seek? :)

Comment: No. I want to execute it in 2 different system

Comment: Also, the OP doesn't mention anything about Grunt